# How to pivot data from row to column with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this data structure in my SQL Server database:

```
User         FmDate          ToDate
------------------------------------
Andy         1/10            1/15
Baey         1/14            1/18
Christy      1/17            2/18
```

The date is range of Nature day, how can I write t-sql to pivot them like excel, as shown:

```
Andy    1/10
Andy    1/11
Andy    1/12
Andy    1/13
Andy    1/14
Andy    1/15
Baey    1/14
Baey    1/15
Baey    1/16
Baey    1/17
Baey    1/18
Christy 1/17
Christy 1/18
```

Comment: What's the datatype of your dates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**tally table**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) to generate the dates from `FmDate` to `ToDate`

```
DECLARE @range INT;
SELECT @range = MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, FmDate, ToDate)) + 1 FROM tbl;

;WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@Range) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteDates([User], dt) AS(
    SELECT t.[User], DATEADD(DAY, N-1, FmDate)
    FROM tbl t
    CROSS JOIN CteTally ct
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, N-1, FmDate) <= ToDate
)
SELECT * 
FROM CteDates
ORDER BY [User], dt;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7d87/3/0)

*This assumes that your dates are of `DATE` format.*

---

*Before your edit, your expected result is a pivoted version.*

To pivot the result of the above, use a [dynamic crosstab](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/). Insert the result of the above to a temp table for processing:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tembTbl') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##tempTbl
END

DECLARE @range INT;
SELECT @range = MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, FmDate, ToDate)) + 1 FROM tbl;

;WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@Range) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteDates([User], dt) AS(
    SELECT t.[User], DATEADD(DAY, N-1, FmDate)
    FROM tbl t
    CROSS JOIN CteTally ct
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, N-1, FmDate) <= ToDate
)
SELECT * 
INTO ##tempTbl
FROM CteDates;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    [User]' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN dt = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dt, 112) + ''' THEN ''Y'' ELSE '''' END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), dt, 101)) + CHAR(10)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT dt FROM ##tempTbl) t 
ORDER BY dt

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM ##tempTbl
GROUP BY [User];'

PRINT (@sql);
EXEC (@sql);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7d87/5/0)

**RESULT:**

```
|    User | 01/10 | 01/11 | 01/12 | 01/13 | 01/14 | 01/15 | 01/16 | 01/17 | 01/18 |
|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|    Andy |     Y |     Y |     Y |     Y |     Y |     Y |       |       |       |
|    Baey |       |       |       |       |     Y |     Y |     Y |     Y |     Y |
| Christy |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |     Y |     Y |
```